# Installing NopCommerce using the Web Platform installer

Tags: iis, nopcommerce

If I install NopCommerce using the Web Platform installer, will the install give me an opportunity to choose the port I want to host it on ? I don't want the install to interfere with the application I already have running on port 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't. And it won't use port 80.

It's not an issue since the Web Platform installer for nopCommerce does *not* create a website in IIS. It creates a WebMatrix project, which hosts your nopCommerce installation in an IIS Express server.